# Magento: Add textboxx on product details page for custom size

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I am working on a jewellery site (developed in magento 1.7), in which I have a ring product. On the details page of rings product, my client wants to show a textbox in which user will enter the size related details.

Price of the product will not vary based on the size entered, this size fields is just for customers reference so that they can make the ring in proper size as user wants.

I have checked but magento doesn't allow textbox on configurable products.

Do anyone know any extension (free or paid) or any code which can help me to achieve this feature in magento.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In your theme, for the file: template/checkout/cart.phtml
Add the new heading along with other heading for cart items.

```
1
<th><?php echo $this->__('Comments') ?></th>
In the file: template/checkout/cart/item/default.phtml
```

Add a new column

```
1
<td class="a-center">
2
<textarea name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][comments]" rows="3" cols="20"><?php echo $_item->getItemcomment() ?></textarea>
3
</td>
```

For Older version of Magento it would be:

```
1
<td class="a-center">
2
<textarea name="cart[<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>][comments]" rows="3" cols="20"><?php echo $this->getItemItemcomment($_item) ?></textarea>
3
</td>
```

The next step is to save the comment in DB, when customer update the cart.

So add a new field ‘itemcomment’ in the tabel ‘sales_flat_quote_item’. (For older version of Magento the table would be ‘sales_quote_item’)

Now we are going to add the code which will do the DB operation. For this we will need to modify the file:
app/code/core/Mage/Checkout/Model/Cart.php (Note: If you are planning to upgrade your Magento setup, copy this file to local & modify.)

Here we need to add some code to the function updateItems(), such a way that the function should now look like below:

```
01
public function updateItems($data)
02
{
03
    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_update_items_before', array('cart'=>$this, 'info'=>$data));
04

05
    foreach ($data as $itemId => $itemInfo) {
06

07
        $item = $this->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
08
        if (!$item) {
09
            continue;
10
        }
11

12
        if (!empty($itemInfo['remove']) || (isset($itemInfo['qty']) && $itemInfo['qty']=='0')) {
13
            $this->removeItem($itemId);
14
            continue;
15
        }
16

17
        $qty = isset($itemInfo['qty']) ? (float) $itemInfo['qty'] : false;
18
        if ($qty > 0) {
19
            $item->setQty($qty);
20
        }
21

22
    /* Start: Custom code added for comments */
23
    if(!empty($itemInfo['comments'])) {
24

25
        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
26

27
        # make the frame_queue active
28
        $query = "UPDATE `sales_flat_quote_item` SET itemcomment = '".$itemInfo['comments']."' where item_id = $itemId";
29
        $write->query($query);
30

31
        $item->setItemcomment($itemInfo['comments']);
32
    }
33
    /* End: Custom code added for comments */
34

35
    }
36

37
    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_update_items_after', array('cart'=>$this, 'info'=>$data));
38
    return $this;
39
}
```

Showing the comment in Admin -> View Order

Add a new function getItemcomment() to the file below:
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Items.php

If you are on verstion 1.5 or later.. add it to the file below.
app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Sales/Order/View/Items.php

```
01
    public function getItemcomment($item) {
02
        $itemId = $item->getId();
03

04
        $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');
05

06
        $query = "SELECT q.* FROM `sales_flat_order_item` o
07
        LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_quote_item` q on o.quote_item_id = q.item_id
08
        WHERE o.item_id = $itemId";
09

10
        # For older versions of Magento
11
/*      $query = "SELECT q.* FROM `sales_order_entity_int` o
12
        LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_quote_item` q on o.value = q.entity_id
13
        WHERE o.entity_id = $itemId AND o.attribute_id = 343";       */    
14

15
        $res = $write->query($query);
16

17
        while ($row = $res->fetch() ) {
18
            if(key_exists('itemcomment',$row)) {
19
                echo nl2br($row['itemcomment']);
20
            }
21
        }
22
    }   
To add the comments column to the items edit the .phtml file below:
app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items.phtml

Adding header for items to make it look like below:

1
.
2
.
3
<tr class="headings">
4
    <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Product') ?></th>
5
    <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Comments') ?></th>
6
    <th><?php echo $this->helper('sales')->__('Item Status') ?></th>
7
.
8
.
9
.
Adding Column with comments. app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml
Add a column for item comments juts before status columns to make it look a like below.

view sourceprint?
1
.
2
.
3
<td><?php echo $this->getItemcomment($_item) ?></td> <!-- New column added for item comments -->
4
<td class="a-center"><?php echo $_item->getStatus() ?></td>
5
.
6
.
```

Doing upto this will show the comments column in the item table. 
This will add a text box with the name as comments(change the name ASAP).Hope this helps.
Note:This will add a box only if the item is added to cart and as you said the price doesn't change I think this would be more appropriate.

Comment: Is it possible to add the same on product details page? As if it is visible only on cart page, then user first add the item to cart and then they will add their ring size details from cart page, which will be 2-step process.

Comment: There is a bug in magento which prevents from making the feature built in or doing so results in error.I have spent more than 2 weeks in researching this but no use believe me.If you find the solution please do share here.I worked as a magento developer in indiaplaza.

Answer (score 1):

I have followed your instructions to add the comment box on my onepage checkout but it's not adding the comment in the database table when I checked it. can you please tell me if I'm doing anything wrong.

below is the function in my Cart.php file that you said to update:

public function updateItems($data)
    {
        Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_update_items_before', array('cart'=>$this, 'info'=>$data));

```
    /* @var $messageFactory Mage_Core_Model_Message */
    $messageFactory = Mage::getSingleton('core/message');
    $session = $this->getCheckoutSession();
    $qtyRecalculatedFlag = false;
    foreach ($data as $itemId => $itemInfo) {
        $item = $this->getQuote()->getItemById($itemId);
        if (!$item) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!empty($itemInfo['remove']) || (isset($itemInfo['qty']) && $itemInfo['qty']=='0')) {
            $this->removeItem($itemId);
            continue;
        }

        $qty = isset($itemInfo['qty']) ? (float) $itemInfo['qty'] : false;
        if ($qty > 0) {
            $item->setQty($qty);

            $itemInQuote = $this->getQuote()->getItemById($item->getId());

            if (!$itemInQuote && $item->getHasError()) {
                Mage::throwException($item->getMessage());
            }

            if (isset($itemInfo['before_suggest_qty']) && ($itemInfo['before_suggest_qty'] != $qty)) {
                $qtyRecalculatedFlag = true;
                $message = $messageFactory->notice(Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Quantity was recalculated from %d to %d', $itemInfo['before_suggest_qty'], $qty));
                $session->addQuoteItemMessage($item->getId(), $message);
            }
        }


        /* Start: Custom code added for comments */
        if(!empty($itemInfo['comments'])) {

            $write = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_write');

            # make the frame_queue active
            $query = "UPDATE `mgn_sales_flat_quote_item` SET itemcomment = '".$itemInfo['comments']."' where item_id = " . $itemId . "";
            $write->query($query);
            $item->setItemcomment($itemInfo['comments']);

        }
        /* End: Custom code added for comments */


    }

    if ($qtyRecalculatedFlag) {
        $session->addNotice(
            Mage::helper('checkout')->__('Some products quantities were recalculated because of quantity increment mismatch')
        );
    }

    Mage::dispatchEvent('checkout_cart_update_items_after', array('cart'=>$this, 'info'=>$data));
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: this should not be posted as an answer, but instead as a comment to the given answer, and the answerer probably does not need you to re-paste all of the code.

Comment: next time you should add additional questions as comments, rather than post questions as an answer